# how to use redis cluster in the gitlab ci and write .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, gitlab-ci

My Spring boot use the redis cluster, but in gitlab
ci ,I only find redis . how can I make the ci with redis cluster?

1. List item

Comment: Redefine your question, make it more clear. Provide example ci.yml for reference. What is it you want to do? It seems like you dont want to use the 'redis' service but your own redis cluster.

Answer (score 0):

.gitlab-ci.yml

`services:
    - grokzen/redis-cluster`

application.yml

`spring:
  redis:
    cluster:
      nodes:
        - grokzen__redis-cluster:7000
        - grokzen__redis-cluster:7001`

it worked.